# alternative to switch/case to reduce program lines

Tags: php, switch-statement

Not too skilled PHP programmer here..
I have a system for screenshots on my site. Using GET and 'switch' I decide upon the screenshot to view from link parameters. Like this:

```
    switch($_GET['scid']) {
    case "1":
    $sc_id_txt = "Default screenshot";
    $picname = "u0"; //Image name
    break;
    case "2":
    $sc_id_txt = "Screenshot no 2";
    $picname = "2";
    break;
    case "3":
    etc..
```

Lots of code for the (up to) 20 screenshots.. In addition, I want the system to be capable of up to 100 screenshots per item.

Is there a better way to achieve the above with fewer lines of code?

Comment: Try something with loops. Maybe an or statement that you can use to modulate the `$picname` and the `$sc_id_txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the rest of them all follow the same pattern, you need only a single if-else:

```
$scid = (int)$_GET['scid'];
if ($scid == 1) {
    $sc_id_txt = "Default screenshot";
    $picname = "u0";
} else if ($scid > 1 && $scid <= 100) {
    $sc_id_txt = "Screenshot no " . $scid;
    $picname = (string)$scid;
}
```

Comment: Learning every day, but not enough, obviously :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In case you have a lot of data and it's dynamic - consider using a database.
In case those values are static or you just don't want database,
use an array to store those values.

```
$screenshots = array(
1 => array('txt' => 'Default Screenshot','pic' => 'u0'),
2 => array('txt' => 'Screenshot2','pic' => '2')
);

$scid = (int)$_GET['scid'];
if($scid == 0 || !array_key_exists($scid, $screenshots))
{
 //Error.
}
else
{
 $screenshot = $screenshots[$scid];
 echo $screenshot['txt'];
 echo $screenshot['pic'];
}
```

Comment: FYI, In case that all your screenshots have the same "format of data" , use @Boann 's solution.

Comment: I have a database. This code is just to find the name of the actual file and the screenshot heading. Folder name and further screenshot information is fetched from the database. Problem is that Im learning every day, and is reluctant to go over all previous code and optimise as I learn new skills.Maybe just an screenshot-database 'id' via GET and all the rest from that database?

Answer (score 1):

I think you dont need a shorter alternative to `SWITCH` - you need to `DRY` (dont repeat yourself).

An example:

Case 2 & 3

```
[...]
case "2":
    $sc_id_txt = "Screenshot no 2";
    $picname = "2";
    break;
case "3":
    $sc_id_txt = "Screenshot no 3";
    $picname = "3";
    break;
case "4": 
[...]
```

this dosnt make sense to repeat..

so just do it like this

```
$scid = (int)$_GET['scid'];
[...]
else if(1 <= $scid and $scid <= 20) {
   $sc_id_text = "Screenshot no {$scid}";
   $pic_name = $scid;
}
[...]
```